# Extract shapes and shape data from GeoTIFF using Rasterio and store as GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I have a GeoTIFF that has a black background and shapes using various colours and each point has a data value. I'm trying to use rasterIO to extract this GeoTIFF into a GeoJSON so it can be displayed on an OpenLayers map. My following code seemingly extracts one shape:

```
import pprint
import rasterio
from rasterio import features

with rasterio.open('../media/Geotiffs/City/1/area_product.tif') as src:
    band= src.read()

mask = band!= 0
shapes = features.shapes(band, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)
pprint.pprint(next(shapes))

# Output
# pprint.pprint(next(shapes))
# ({'coordinates': [[(71.0, 6.0),
#                    (71.0, 7.0),
#                    (72.0, 7.0),
#                    (72.0, 6.0),
#                    (71.0, 6.0)]],
#   'type': 'Polygon'},
# 253)
```

The format isn't right as it has () around each coordinate and I can't work out how to extract the value of each point at that moment. my goal is to write a GeoJSON with the following structure.

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [{ LOOP FOR EACH SHAPE
        "type" : "Feature", 
        "properties" : {  
            "value": SHAPE VALUE
        }, 
        "geometry" : { 
            "type" : "Polygon", 
            "coordinates" : [ SHAPE CO-ORDINATES 
                             [ -71.073283, 42.417500 ],
                             [ -71.073283, 42.417500 ],
                             [ -71.073283, 42.417500 ],
                             [ -71.073283, 42.417500 ],
                            ] 
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shapes` returns an iterable of tuples with geometry and value, you can use geopandas to parse the geometry into a valid geojson.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterio import features


with rasterio.open('test.tif') as src:
    band=src.read()

    mask = band!= 0
    shapes = features.shapes(band, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)

fc = ({"geometry": shape, "properties": {"value": value}} for shape, value in shapes)

gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(fc).to_json()
# Or
# gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(fc).to_file('test.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

Comment: Thanks so much this has been bugging me all week!

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer!
I'm facing an issue though.
After plotting the coordinates in QGIS, it is not the correct geographical location. Even though I have plotted the mask (GeoTIFF raster) in QGIS and it appears in the right place, why is that?